# Passing php variable to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a variable which stores the path of the file. I am using a pop up window to display that image. I am using following script

```
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
```

Using it as

```
echo '<td width="150"><a href="JavaScript:newPopup(\'ajax-loader.gif\');">ScreenShot</a></td>';
```

When I give the name not stored in variable as mentioned above, the script works fine. But when I try to give the variable $end_file, it is not working. I have tried following combinations

```
 echo '<td width="150"><a href="JavaScript:newPopup(\''.'$end_file'.'\');">ScreenShot</a></td>';
 echo '<td width="150"><a href="JavaScript:newPopup(\'{$end_file}\');">ScreenShot</a></td>';
```

But none seems to work

Comment: are you using `smarty`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around `'$end_file'` in your first example and it should work.

```
echo '<td width="150"><a href="JavaScript:newPopup(\''.$end_file.'\');">ScreenShot</a></td>';
```

For the second example, I believe you have to use double-quotes for string-iterpolation to work.

```
echo "<td width='150'><a href='JavaScript:newPopup(\"$end_file\");'>ScreenShot</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<td width="150"><a href="JavaScript:newPopup(\"'.$end_file.'\");">ScreenShot</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following :

```
<?php
$x="PHP";
?>    
<script>alert("Hello from <?php echo $x;?>");</script>
```